# How do I restart the Samba service?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba

I have changed the config file, but changes are not appearing.
Do I have to restart Samba?

Answer (score 11):

It looks like ubuntu has changed the name of the service you need to restart to smbd.  For me (on ubuntu server 12.04) the correct command was

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Editor's notes:
I can't comment, or this would be a comment to the above answer.
I realize this is an old question, but I landed here looking for the very same thing, and the comment was enough of a hint to me to figure out the rest, so I thought I'd record the update.

Answer (score 9):

`sudo /etc/init.d/samba restart` should be all you need to do.

Comment: sudo service samba restart
 `sudo service samba restart`. Looks like windows :))

Answer (score 5):

In a production environment it's not advisable to restart a service for just configuration changes. I suggest you go with:

```
sudo service smbd reload
```

Whats the advantage of reload?

Reload will just update the configuration changes, with out restarting the service.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try this:

```
systemctl restart smbd
systemctl restart nmbd
```

This will work if you are using systemd.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version in 2021, the following will work perfectly:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart
```

Please see that the only difference is in the pid file name.